# Runtime Binder Exception

Tags: c#, wpf

After a deserialization I save the content in an object:

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseText);
```

so I execute a loop for populate a DataGrid

```
foreach(var item in obj)
{ 
     MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
     {
          code = item.code,
          name = item.name,
          shortName = item.shortName,
          squadMarketValue = item.squadMarketValue
     });
}
```

The problem's that inside the foreach the compiler show `Runtime Binder Exception`.
Why happean this?

Some more details:

**Class structure**

```
 public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fixtures
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Players
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public Fixtures fixtures { get; set; }
        public Players players { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string squadMarketValue { get; set; }
        public string crestUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

JSON structure:

```
{
"_links": {
     "self": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19" },
     "fixtures": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/fixtures" },
     "players": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/players" }
   },
   "name": "Eintracht Frankfurt",
   "code": "SGE",
   "shortName": "Eintr. Frankfurt",
   "squadMarketValue": "75.475.000 ?",
   "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Eintracht_Frankfurt_Logo.svg"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you are deserializing does not contain a property named code.  So the line `code = item.code` causes an exception at runtime, because the Json.Net object behind the `dynamic` does not contain a value named `code`.

This means that the Json that you are parsing does not contain a property named `code`.  Or else it only sometimes contains a property named code.  In that case you'll have to either parse it is a `JObject` and check if the property exists or create an type do deserialize it into.'

***Edit***

Based on the Json that you posted along with the class structure it looks like you should just be deserializing directly into a `RootObject` class:

```
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

Or in any case you can still deserialize into a `dynamic` but you need to get rid of the `foreach` since you don't have a collection of `RootObject`

```
 var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseText);

MainWindow.AppWindow.Squadre_DataGrid.Items.Add(new Teams.Club_Information
{
    code = obj.code,
    name = obj.name,
    shortName = obj.shortName,
    squadMarketValue = obj.squadMarketValue
 });
```

Where you went wrong was the `foreach`.  Since `obj` is `dynamic` there is no compiler error and the Json.Net `JObject` that is returned supports iteraction.  But the that gives you back each of the property values, (e.g. _links, name, etc) on at a time, not the object that you are interested in.

Comment: It depends on what your Json object looks like.  It doesn't appear to have a property named code.  Take a look at the json you  are deserializing and see what properties it does have.

Comment: And is that exactly what responseText looks like?  In your example code your are iterating over a list of items, but the json you posted only has a single object.  Could you also please update your question with the exact json that you are trying to parse.

Comment: Sure, I post the json structure.

Comment: Yeah but I need to iterate all elements :\